# Springboot: java.lang.NullPointerException @autowired in component class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I am new to springboot, i have create a component class which is auto wired in a service class, i have a DAO class implemented when i try to autowired in to component class i am getting NullPointerException, am able to user the method of DAO if in do it in service class

My application is structured as follows:

Service class

```
@Service
public class MyService implements IMyService{

    @Autowired
    IMyComponent myComp;

    @Override
    public sFunc(){
     myComp.cFunc();
    }

}
```

Component class

```
@Component
public class MyComponent implements IMyComponent{

    @Autowired
    IMyDAO mydao;

    @Override
    public cFunc(){
     mydao.daoFunc();
    }
}
```

DAO class

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class MyDAO implements IMyDAO{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public daoFunc(){
      sysout("here");
    }
}
```

Is this flow correct did?

Comment: Where do you get this exception?

Comment: if DAO method is called in the component class getting null pointer exception,
if the same method is called in service class then there is no exception.